# How to eliminate rows by using WHERE out of concatenated columns?

Tags: sql, jdbc, teradata

any idea how to eliminate rows by using WHERE out of concatenated columns?

so say:

```
SELECT company_id||department_id AS "Company Dept" FROM Department
```

I've tried to further narrow down by:

```
WHERE company_id||department_id='000159999'
```

However, it didn't work. Wondering any possible solutions to filter from the concatenated columns (in Teradata JDBC)?

Company_id=00015; department_id=9999 
Take a note that the same function departments could be in different department IDs in different company codes. That's why my ideal filter would be out of the concatenated columns.

Thank in advance!

Comment: What does "didn't" work mean in detail?

Comment: well..there is an error saying "Bad character in format or data of (table name)".

Answer (score 2):

Why would you concatenate the values together?  Just use:

```
WHERE company_id = '00015'  and department_id = '9999'
```

From a performance perspective, this is better, because the query can take advantage of indexing (and statistics are more accurate).  If the values are really numbers, then drop the `'`s and leading `0`s:

```
WHERE company_id = 15 and department_id = 9999
```

If you have multiple values you are looking for:

```
WHERE (company_id = 15 and department_id = 9999) or
      (company_id = 14 and department_id = 9998) or
      . . .
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for helping! I would need more departments and more company codes, not just 9999 or 15. While 9999 is the one I need for the company code 15, but I don't need 9999 in company code 14 or 13. While I need 9998 in company code 14, but i don't need 9998 from company code 13.........etc......So if I filter separately for both company codes and department ID, the result will include those rows I don't need. Does that make sense? Thanks for helping :)